# Will the market price be definitely lower than 'after hours' number?

Tags: stocks, after-hours-trading

I purchased a stock but sadly forget to sell at a very good timing because its quarterly report indicates its benefit below expectation.

But the time that report was released is not in the trading hours.

So here is what I see:

[image]

I am very new to stocks trading and I have no idea what `After Hours` price stands for.

What would happen if I sell the stock tomorrow while market is opened? Say if I request an order to sell the stock at market price, it'd be sold at `< 18.76USD`?

Thanks,

Comment: $18.76 is an indication of what it will open at the next day but that may change with pre-open trading the next day.

Comment: @Victor Thanks. What is `pre-open trading`? Can I trade at that moment? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short. No.  The after hours market price reflects things such as limit orders and orders closing out from the day after market hours.  It could, for instance, reflect poor news, whereby many people put in sell orders to execute at open or limit orders below the current bid.  However, as is oftern the case, people overreact.

With regards to your question about selling price.  If you placed as order to sell at market it would execute in the order recived (usually) at the current bid, which will likely not be the after hours price.  On the other hand, if you put a limit sell in at 18.76, then the selling price will be at or above the 18.76.  The limit sell says "get me at least 18,76".